# What is the best way to select data in a JSON data object?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm calling a JSON object and in Firebug it returns this response :

```
"[{\"employee\":{\"account_id\":1,\"active\":true,\"activity_ical_hash\":\"af2d0f784ce28bc16d6fdf593d3e4bc7\",\"address\":null,\"admin\":false,\"all_tasks_ical_hash\":\"d4067eceea22b2f281c65f22ccc7820f\",\"always_send_daily_schedule\":true,\"api_token\":\"8d4ab012505392a25d1469e33945d9b05365eedb\",\"can_login\":true,\"cell_phone\":null,\"city\":null,\"created_at\":\"2012-02-20T09:41:27-08:00\",\"custom_datetime1\":null,\"custom_datetime10\":null,\"custom_datetime2\":null,\"custom_datetime3\":null,\"custom_datetime4\":null,\"custom_datetime5\":null,\"custom_datetime6\":null,\"custom_datetime7\":null,\"custom_datetime8\":null,\"custom_datetime9\":null,\"custom_number1\":null,\"custom_number10\":null,\"custom_number2\":null,\"custom_number3\":null,\"custom_number4\":null,\"custom_number5\":null,\"custom_number6\":null,\"custom_number7\":null,\"custom_number8\":null,\"custom_number9\":null,\"custom_text1\":null,\"custom_text10\":null,\"custom_text2\":null,\"custom_text3\":null,\"custom_text4\":null,\"custom_text5\":null,\"custom_text6\":null,\"custom_text7\":null,\"custom_text8\":null,\"custom_text9\":null,\"email_address\":\"mckenna_moore@schumm.org\",\"email_schedule_daily\":true,\"employee_number\":4,\"hashed_password\":\"cbc689313dfd6fd144f7df117c4f18e1627afde4\",\"hide_pricing\":null,\"home_phone\":null,\"id\":4,\"is_account_owner\":false,\"jobs_ical_hash\":\"d51abd7af0326083f9d25c4aacc828c0\",\"limit_access_to_assignments\":false,\"name\":\"Horacio Johnson\",\"notification_email_address\":\"tyrell.bartoletti@donnellyerdman.biz\",\"notification_mobile_host\":null,\"notification_mobile_number\":null,\"notify_on_tasks\":true,\"notify_on_tasks_by_sms\":true,\"notify_via_email\":true,\"notify_via_mobile\":false,\"pager\":null,\"public_tasks_ical_hash\":\"592b2d4150ef46821c2ae8df63ca686d\",\"remember_me_token\":null,\"remember_me_token_expires_at\":null,\"salt\":\"35f1a3c4\",\"show_setup_tab\":null,\"state\":null,\"tech\":true,\"updated_at\":\"2012-02-20T09:41:27-08:00\",\"username\":\"user_marguerite\",\"zip_code\":null}}]"
```

What syntax would be required to return the `name` attribute in each returned element?

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
$.getJSON(window.location.pathname+'.json?employees='+$("input").attr('value'), function(data){

           $available_names = []
              $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                $name = val.name;
                $available_names.push($name);
              });

});
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

**Update**

Trying to add an error handler on this method and this won't even run. It fails for some syntactical reason :

```
$.getJSON(window.location.pathname+'.json?employees='+$("input").attr('value'), function(data){

}).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: Got any errors? You missing ; at the end of $available_names = []

Comment: None. I'm also trying to do a simple alert and it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Add this to the end of your getJSON call and see if you get something: .error(function() { alert("error"); })

Comment: You have an array called `$available_names`, but when you push to it you use `$avaiable_names`. If this typo is on your actual code, you should fix it too.

Comment: @bfavaretto: yah sorry, that was a type. not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in an Array structure. It appears as though it's meant to be an Array of employee objects.

To get the name of each employee, you'd need to access the `employee` property of each object.

```
  $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    $name = val.employee.name;
    $avaiable_names.push($name);
  });
```

...but if you're building an Array, you could use `$.map` instead...

```
  var $avaiable_names = $.map(data, function(val, i) {
      return val.employee.name;
  });
```

---

If it still  isn't working, then check to see if your JSON is being double encoded. There's something about that Firebug output that makes me think that may be the case.

You can test this by having the response parsed again, like this...

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

If it starts working, then it is definitely being double encoded on the server, so you'd want to fix that.

Comment: So weird, I totally thought this would have worked. But nothing happens.

Comment: @Trip: Check out the bottom part of my answer that I added. The Firebug output makes it look like the response is being double encoded. Try the `$.parseJSON` line, and if that clears it up, then you'll want to fix it on the server side.

Comment: In regards to the double parsing.. I get an error saying `j is null` which makes me think it's not double parsed, that's just Firebug converting it to a string.

Comment: @Trip: Have you verified that the callback is invoked at all? What do you get if you `alert(typeof data)`?

Comment: Yes, because Firebug recognizes the object in the DOM, and I can paste the responseText above.

Comment: @Trip: How is Firebug giving you that output? Are you doing a `console.log(data)`? Did you try the `alert(typeof data)` in the callback?

Comment: @Trip: I'm curious to know what the issue ended up being.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your JSON structure do you want to be doing this:

```
$name = val.employee.name
```